# Users upload images via text message

Tags: images, uploading

I was playing around in Photobucket and saw the upload via text message option. (Each users gets a unique "number") Does anyone know how to accomplish this or lead me in the right direction for it? I think this would be a great feature for a project I work on.

Comment: (Text message = MMS). Bit of an aside, but from a users perspective... Not sure what it's like in the US, but in the UK, sending MMS are relatively expensive as they are rarely included in price plans. Consequently they are rarely used and considered a "last resort" (IMHO).

Comment: At the very least, you'd need a shortcode or a phone number to receive the messages. Could you have the users simply email their pictures to a randomly generated user-specific email address?

Comment: I just created a photobucket account and checked, and that's how they do it ... email addresses, not quite the same thing as MMS

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of sms gateway providers who offer this service. Firstly there is no need to have a unique number for each user, you can have a single number that all members send images to and they simply have to register their mobile number with the application first so that any images sent in from their mobile number will automatically be associated with their account.

One provider which supports this is Twilio and you can see information on how to do it at https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-send-or-receive-mms-messages.